# Bluemix spark service error: java.net.NoRouteToHostException

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, spark-notebook

Yesterday, this code ran ok.  However today I get the following error message:

```
df = sqlContext.read.jdbc(
    url="jdbc:db2://bluemix05.bluforcloud.com:50001/BLUDB:user=****;password=****;sslConnection=true;",  
    table="GOSALES.BRANCH"
).cache()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
...

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.jdbc.
: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.19.26] Exception java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Error opening socket to server bluemix05.bluforcloud.com/50.97.93.115 on port 50,001 with message: No route to host. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kd.a(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to try and open up the dashDB service directly in Bluemix which shown me that the dashDB service was unavailable:

[image]